# Swift - UI Button : Animated Button crosses the edge

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I have a UIButton in my ViewController. This button is moving to 4 adjusted positions when click on it. **The problem is that the UIButton move over the edge when I run the project in iphone 5s simulator .**

In addition adjusted postitons dont work correctly .

```
    let size : CGSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0);
    var intStep = 0;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.movable_Button.frame.size = size;


        self.changePosition();


    }


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {



            self.changePosition();
        }

    }

    func changePosition() {

        switch self.intStep {
        case 0 :
            self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0);

        case 1 :

            self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 10)
        case 2 :
            self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 280.0, y: 300.0);

        case 3 :
            self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 300.0);
        default:
            self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0);
        }

        self.intStep += 1;

        if self.intStep > 3
        {
            self.intStep = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Share a screenshot plz @mehran-debug.

Comment: " UIButton move over the edge ": Do you mean that on a bigger phone, it doesn't? You set `CGPoint(x: 280.0, y: 300.0);`, is that a valid point? Will the button be visible then? https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions It has "320" of width, and you button is 100 of width... It should go over edge then...

Comment: i added a screen shot - it happend when button move to second position

Comment: Rather than set the frame, enable/disable constraints relative to the screen edges (or whatever's appropriate).

Comment: is there any way to use this method and doesnt use constraint without this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do here?
It seems you're moving your `x` value for the button go beyond the screen limit for iPhone 5s.

I suggest you change some of your cases to make it adjustable.
A suggested change might be:

```
    case 1 :
    let isMovable1 = (self.movable_Button.frame.origin.x + 280 + 100) < UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: isMovable1 ? 280 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, y: 10)
    case 2 :
    let isMovable2 = (self.movable_Button.frame.origin.x + 280 + 100) < UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        self.movable_Button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: isMovable2 ? 280 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, y: 10)
```

Comment: I would suggest using auto layout animations instead, but since you got it working..